# Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor '...IHostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I've been reading what I can find on Dependency Injection, but I can't seem to figure out what I have wrong here. I have a background service that can be set to run once a day which works fine. The background service will run daily and check if any row in a column has a date sooner than today. the issue comes when I attempt to combine it with a DB context so that it can do what I want. Here is my attempt to retrieve the table data.

```
public class GetSR : IGetSR
    {
        private readonly Template.Data.ServiceContext _context;

        public GetSR(Template.Data.ServiceContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<ServiceSummary> Service_Request_Informations { get; set; }

        public async Task GetRequests()
        {
            IQueryable<ServiceSummary> listIQ = from s in _context.Summary select s;
            listIQ = listIQ.Where(s => s.FollowUpDate < DateTime.Now);
            Service_Request_Informations = await listIQ.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

This is the interface:

```
public interface IGetSR
{
    Task GetRequests();
}
```

Here is my background service:

```
public class ScheduledUpdate : BackgroundService
{
    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        ...
    }

    public ScheduledUpdate(IGetSR GetSR)
    {
        _Requests = GetSR;
    }
    public readonly IGetSR _Requests;
}
```

Startup.cs

```
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddRazorPages();

     services.AddTransient<IGetSR, GetSR>();
...
}
...
```

My code will not build anymore. If I understand DI correctly, I should not need to scope IGetSR to BackgroundService like I do GetSR, yet it says it cannot be scoped. What am I doing wrong here?

SOLVED: Thanks to Compufreak. I needed to make some adjustments to work for me

```
protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    using var scope = _ServiceProvider.CreateScope();
    var requests = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IGetSR>();

    var DailyTime = "15:00:00";
    var timeParts = DailyTime.Split(new char[1] { ':' });

    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
        var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day, int.Parse(timeParts[0]), int.Parse(timeParts[1]), int.Parse(timeParts[2]));
        TimeSpan ts;

        if (date > dateNow)
        {
            ts = date - dateNow;
        }
        else
        {
            date = date.AddDays(1);
            ts = date - dateNow;
        }

        await Task.Delay(ts, stoppingToken);
        await requests.GetRequests();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A background service cannot be scoped as a scope in a .NET Core-Web Application usually gets initialized by a webrequest. A background service works independently of webrequests by design.

But you can inject the ServiceProvider and create your own scope inside your BackgroundService:

```
public class ScheduledUpdate : BackgroundService
{
    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using ( var scope = this.services.CreateScope() )
        {
            var requests = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IGetSR>();
        }
    }

    public ScheduledUpdate(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    private readonly IServiceProvider _ServiceProvider;
}
```

A DbContext is designed to be scoped, so you should not change it to not be scoped. It's needed for stuff like a clean dispose / pooling of database connections.

Comment: Thanks for answering! And my code can build now. It wasn't my intention to try to "de-scope" DbContext. If I could accomplish the same thing by just calling a function in another class that **is** within scope, I would do that instead because that is essentially all i am trying to accomplish. The background service doesn't have to know what is going on, it just needs to kick off the thing that does.

Comment: I see, but the concept does remain the same. If you want to use a service that needs a scoped service, you need a scope. So for every interaction with DbContext - no matter how deeply it is nested - you need to get a scope from somewhere (or initialize it yourself, what is not a thing I would recommend).